# How to create new activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am completely new to Android Studio and I was wondering when I create a new class, it doesn't contain the method `public void onCreate`. For example in my `main_activity` you have the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` that would let you connect to your `layout` and then do things with `fields` or `buttons`. My question is how can I do the same when I create a new class. Do I just copy the `public void onCreate` into the new class and go about it that way. Or do I `extend` from `main_activity`. Really confused and trying to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it will be complicated.

**Simplest Way**: What you can do is right click on the java folder, located on the left side in Android Studio. Then, go to "New" on the top. Look downwards and you will see "Activity". Hover on that and it will give you some different types of activities that you can create. By clicking on one of them, it automatically adds that activity to your `AndroidManifest` and it also creates the Java class, and XML file for the activity.

**Longer Way**: As you mentioned, you can copy and paste the `onCreate` method into the class. You would also have to add `extends AppCompatActivity`. Then, you will have to add the class to `AndroidManifest` by doing

```
   <activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:label="My Activity"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme" />
```

Next, you will have to create an XML file. To the top of your file, you should add:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **tools:context=".ActivityName"**>
```

Finally, you will have to go to your Java class and add the following in `onCreate`:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.mylayoutfile);
```

These are two ways that you can create an activity.

Comment: So every time you add a new activity you have to also add it into the `Androidmanifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes. You have to do that.

Comment: If this answer helped you moegizzle, please mark it as accepted so that those who are facing similar problems can refer to this answer to get help as well.

Comment: I am happy that I was able to help moegizzle!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the resource link : [Create New Activity](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-add-activity-in-android-studio/)

This will create java class and the xml interface at the same time and it will add necessary lines to manifest.xml too